# How to invoke custom function to apply in query files with different columns range?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.masterdataanalysis.com/ms-excel/import-clean-file-folder/) to import files from a folder and clean them. However, for that example every .xls file has the same amount of columns. In my case, I have this (after cleaning):

```
| Col1 | Col2 |
|------|------|
| 1    | 3    |
| 4    | 2    |
```

and

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    3 |    4 |    8 |
|    4 |    7 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

And I want to have this result:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |    - |
|    4 |    2 |    - |
|    3 |    4 |    8 |
|    4 |    7 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

My custom function looks like this (replaced columns by etc as they are almost two thousand). I suppose I'll have to  delete both `#"Changed Type"` steps, but how can I remove the rows I don't want?

```
(ExcelFile) =>
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(ExcelFile, null, true),
#"CMG Barras pesos_Sheet" = Source{[Item="CMG Barras pesos",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"CMG Barras pesos_Sheet",{"Column1", type any}, etc)
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",8),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Barra", type any}, etc),
#"Removed Top Rows1" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type1",1)
in
#"Removed Top Rows1"
```

Comment: If you remove the `#"Changed Type"` steps, does it not work how you want? Those look like the only lines that refer to column names.

Comment: @AlexisOlson You are so right. Thanks a lot, if you put it as an answer I'll mark  your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"#Changed Type"` steps are the only ones in your function that refer to columns individually. The others are just removing (skipping) a few rows of the table and promoting a row to be the column names.

There are ways to deal with variable numbers of columns, but in your case, I don't think you need to do anything fancy. Just take out those steps:

```
    (ExcelFile) =>
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(ExcelFile, null, true),
    #"CMG Barras pesos_Sheet" = Source{[Item="CMG Barras pesos",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"CMG Barras pesos_Sheet",8),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Top Rows1" = Table.Skip(#"Promoted Headers",1)
in
    #"Removed Top Rows1"
```